# Add legend for forecast and actual values in R forecasting

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, forecasting

I'm trying to add a legend to a timeseries plot showing the actual data and the forecast data.

I have a model that is built using training data stored in a tbl_ts and then used to forecast the next 60 days.

I have the this code which gives the following graph

```
data <- tsibble(
  date = as.Date("2017-01-01") + 0:729,
  value = rnorm(730)
)

train_data <- data %>%
  slice(1:670)

test_data <- data %>%
  slice(n() -59:0)

naive_model_all <- data %>%
  model(SNAIVE(value))

 naive_model_all %>%
  forecast(h=60) %>%
  autoplot(data)+
  labs(y="Value",
       x="Date")
```

[Graph produced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkctF.png)

What I'm looking to do is to add a legend to state that black is actual values and blue is forecast values.

I have tried the following but it doesn't give a legend and just produces the same graph as before.

```
naive_model_all %>%
  forecast(h=60) %>%
  autoplot(series='Forecast') + 
  autolayer(data, series='Data')+
  guides(colour=guide_legend(title="Data series"), 
         fill=guide_legend(title="Prediction interval"))
```

It also gives warnings that 'series' is an unknown parameter.

```
1: In distributional::geom_hilo_ribbon(intvl_mapping, data = dplyr::anti_join(interval_data,  :
  Ignoring unknown parameters: `series`
2: In distributional::geom_hilo_linerange(intvl_mapping, data = dplyr::semi_join(interval_data,  :
  Ignoring unknown parameters: `series`
3: In geom_line(mapping = mapping, data = dplyr::anti_join(object,  :
  Ignoring unknown parameters: `series`
4: In ggplot2::geom_point(mapping = mapping, data = dplyr::semi_join(object,  :
  Ignoring unknown parameters: `series`
5: In geom_line(eval_tidy(expr(aes(!!!aes_spec))), data = object, ...,  :
  Ignoring unknown parameters: `series
```

How do I get a legend to appear to show the actual data in black and the forecast data in blue?
Thanks

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.